# Objective-C : UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL get ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

When the user selects an image using the UIImagePickerController, the UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL gives me the following:

```
UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=7F96E032-2342-4FED-B0A6-EE0EC3C7A540&ext=PNG
```

Can somebody please tell me how it is possible to pull out the id from this URL? (7F96E032-2342-4FED-B0A6-EE0EC3C7A540)

Also, I am assuming that this will be a unique value for every image? Is this correct?

Comment: You need to use the `NSURL` methods to get the query string and then parse the query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can somebody please tell me how it is possible to pull out the id from this URL

Don't even think of doing so.

Instead, use Photo Kit. You have the asset URL, so fetch the asset with `fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:`. Now ask the asset for its `localIdentifier`. This, and only this, is the unique identifier.